# Managing unique IDs on deletion in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

My title may be a little off, but I'm not sure how to explain it.

I'm currently working on a photo portfolio where the user will be able
to upload images from a web interface. When this is done, the following happens:

The image is uploaded via a HTML-form -> PHP.
A SQL-record is created holding the following information:

```
ID (Autoincrement) - Image title - Image Desc - Filepath
```

The user is also able to administer their uploads via another page in the web interface.
When this happens, the SQL-record is deleted together with the file. However, when the
user then adds a new file, the next ID number is used, leaving the database with an empty space where the deleted record used to be.

I understand that this is because autoincrement is not to be used for IDs displayed to the user, but for other purposes. However, as I'm ftmb using this information to display the photo number in the image viewer, i'd like a more suitable approach. What I need is essentially a MySQL-column containing ints that will fill the gaps created when deleting records. For example:

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8
```

Upon deleting record 5, I need the IDs to fill the gaps so I instead of

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 -   - 6 - 7 - 8
```

Get
    1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7

Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: It just sounds like a *display problem* that has nothing much to do with the database really. Can you not simply number the images when you output them, regardless of their id in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have a good facility to do this automatically, but you can do it manually with something like:

```
SELECT sequence_number FROM photo WHERE photo_id = 729; -- This would be 5.
DELETE FROM photo WHERE photo_id=729;
UPDATE photo SET sequence_number = sequence_number - 1 WHERE sequence_number > 5;
```

The `UPDATE` query can include whatever other conditions (e.g., a matching `album_id`) would describe the set of pictures whose numbers are meant to be sequential.

However, having said that, if you're just always displaying a sequential number to the user, why does it need to be stored in the database at all? When your PHP code is iterating over the results, simply add the number there.

```
$sequence_number = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    // ... Display everything ...
    $sequence_number++;
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, that's the correct approach. (Do make sure that where you have `idvariable` you are using either parameterized queries or, at least, `mysql_real_escape_string` to ensure you are not directly injecting `$_GET` arguments into your query.) Both the `729` I used and, of course, the `5` will necessarily be variables in any case, since you obviously won't be deleting the same photo every time.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE `<table>` SET `<table>`.`<column>` = @count:= @count + 1;
```

The query above will loop and go through each row and update the `<column>` field with a sequential integer.

This should answer your question, but to my understanding your issue with the image viewer might be something completely different and not related to the auto increment problem.

Comment: This would modify the actual `PRIMARY KEY` / `AUTO_INCREMENT`, which is strongly discouraged. The question here is how to modify a separate column used specifically for this purpose.

Comment: As I described: this is exactly what I try to avoid, as well as any ALTER suggestions. Thanks for the suggestion, however!